# Como crear un Json personalizado en .NET

Tags: c#, json, poo, .net, serialización

Cordial saludo.

Actualemte estoy trabajado con objetos este es el Objeto:

```
namespace Acapulco.Models

{
    public class Transport
    {

        public string FlightCarrier { get; set; }
        public string FlightNumber { get; set; }

        public Transport(string FlightCarrier, string FlightNumber)
        {
            this.FlightCarrier = FlightCarrier;
            this.FlightNumber = FlightNumber;
        }

        public Transport() { 
        }

    }
}
```

Y lo que necesito es mappearlo a Json pero no con Json.Serialize(Obj)... Por que lo que requiero es cambiar los encabezados de la siguiente manera:

```
[{vuelo:xxx, numero:xxx},{vuelo:xxx, numero:xxx},{vuelo:xxx, numero:xxx}...]
```

Como hago para cambiarle el Header al Json o para retornar un Json personalizado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suponiendo que estas con .NET (es decir NET 5/6/7) puedes utilizar el componente/assembly [System.Text.Json](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-7.0) que tiene [JsonSerializer.Serialize](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serialize?view=net-7.0), como es tambien un [libreria nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json) lo puedes utilizar en NET Framework 7/4.8.

Se realiza con el metodo [JsonSerializer.Serialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serialize?view=net-7.0) pero agregando atributos, la palabra correcta seria "decorando" con el atributo [JsonPropertyName](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=net-7.0) a las propiedades para que el serializador pueda "cambiar de nombre" tanto para serializar como deserializar te puede ayudar.

Te dejo un ejemplo para ejecutar

- [JsonSerializer-Serialize-JsonPropertyName](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JJOyvL) > https://dotnetfiddle.net/JJOyvL

El codigo

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("JSON Serialize");
        
        var vuelos = new List<Transport>();
        
        vuelos.Add(new Transport("111", "A222"));
        vuelos.Add(new Transport("333", "B444"));
        vuelos.Add(new Transport("555", "C555"));

        
        var jsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(vuelos);
    
        Console.WriteLine(jsonData);
    }
}

    
    public class Transport
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("vuelo")]
        public string FlightCarrier { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("numero")]
        public string FlightNumber { get; set; }

        public Transport(string flightCarrier, string flightNumber)
        {
            FlightCarrier = flightCarrier;
            FlightNumber = flightNumber;
        }

        public Transport() { 
        }
    }
```

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [Serialización y deserialización de JSON en .NET: información general](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/overview)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.

Answer (score 1):

Solo basta con agregar el atributo [JsonPropertyName("LoQueSea")]

Este seria el codigo:

```
namespace Acapulco.Models
{
    public class Transport
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Vuelo")]
        public string FlightCarrier { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("Numero")]
        public string FlightNumber { get; set; }

        public Transport(string FlightCarrier, string FlightNumber)
        {
            this.FlightCarrier = FlightCarrier;
            this.FlightNumber = FlightNumber;
        }

        public Transport() { 
        }



    }
}
```